# How to make chat input stick to bottom of page with sidebar using tailwind css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a chat ui using tailwind css. What i am trying to create is a sidebar annotated with a message list view and lastly, a input to send message. I am unable to get the desired view. If you run this code using tailwind css `input_message` div doesn't match the width of parent div, also when I use `w-full` for `input_message`, width becomes more than parent. Following is only the dummy design to tone down the issue I am facing currently.

```
<div class="flex h-screen">
  <div class="sidebar m-0 h-full w-1/5 border border-gray-500">Side Bar for chat list</div>
  <div class="m-0 h-full w-4/5 border border-gray-500">
    <div class="messages border border-gray-900">messages list</div>
    <div class="input_message absolute bottom-0 border border-gray-900">input message</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to try the same: https://play.tailwindcss.com/aERqae8v1B

Can anyone please tell me solution for the same? What i want is to make `input_message` width to be same as that of parent. I am new to html and css and I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to be working

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tested and got one solution: https://play.tailwindcss.com/sSjxpht6wp . Wondering if this the right way to do it?

Comment: It looks okay to me

Answer (score 3):

I will work with grid and flex in this case.
Something like that:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-5 grid-rows-1 ">
  <div class="sidebar border-gray-500 bg-slate-500">
    Side Bar for chat list
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-col justify-between w-full h-screen col-span-4">
    <div class="messages w-full border border-gray-90">
      messages list
    </div>
    <div class="inputmessage w-full border border-gray-900">
      input message
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/x119T4d7JQ

Comment: Looks pretty clean. 

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like [this](https://play.tailwindcss.com/byoBnsEd4n)

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="w-1/5 border-2 h-screen">
      Sidebar for chat box
  </div>
  <div class="flex w-full flex-col justify-between ">
    <div class="border-2">Messages List</div>
    <div class="border-2">input chat box List</div>
  </div>
</div>
```